# Get the max element in an array that ends with a 0

Tags: c++, arrays

So, I am writing a code which creates an array with an elements and amount of elements written by user and then a code generates a biggest value which last digit is zero. So, I have accomplished a step of writing an array which is elements entered by user. The hardest part( for me) is to complete a code which **generates biggest value which last digit is zero**. So yeah, I need an advice in completing this code. Thank you.

for example :

An array - `2 20 25 300 55555`
The biggest number which last digit is zero is 300

So yeah, I need an advice in completing this code. Here is a code what I have done so far :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

int GetAmount() {
    int howmany;
    printf("Enter amount of elements - ");
    scanf_s("%i", &howmany);
    return howmany;
}

void GetArray(int a[], int n) {
    printf("Enter elements - \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   printf("%i ->", i);
        scanf_s("%i", &a[i]);

    }
}

int LastDigitZero(int n[], int a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        if (n[i] % 10 == 0) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}

int maxvalue(int a[], int n) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] > temp) {
            temp = a[i];
        }   
    }
    return temp;
}



void main() {
    int amount = GetAmount();
    int array[100];
    GetArray(array, amount);
    int max = maxvalue(array, amount);
    printf("Max Value is %i\n", max);
}
```

Thank you for your attention, have a nice day! :)

Comment: I dont know about visual c++ but i know about c++ but still if you want max num with last digit 0 you may have to check `if(num%10==0 && a[i]>temp)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost have it.  First any number that ends in 0 mod 10 is 0 so that is how you can check if the last digit is 0.  With that you would change `maxvalue()` to

```
int maxvalue(int a[], int n) {
    int temp = a[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] % 10 == 0 && a[i] > temp) {
            temp = a[i];
        }   
    }
    return temp;
}
```

I also made a change to set temp to the value of `a[0]` as if your array is all negative numbers then 0 would be the largest number.  Since `temp` is already `a[0]` we can then start the for loop at 1.

Comment: I am sorry, If I understand right, I am not able to vote at all until I get 15 reputation. But I would like to give you  +1. The only thing is that I can't

Answer (score 1):

It works! That's how it looks!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

int GetAmount() {
    int howmany;
    printf("Enter amount of elements - ");
    scanf_s("%i", &howmany);
    return howmany;
}

void GetArray(int a[], int n) {
    printf("Enter elements - \n");
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   printf("%i ->", i);
        scanf_s("%i", &a[i]);

    }
}


int maxvalue(int a[], int n) {
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] % 10 == 0 && a[i] > temp) {
            temp = a[i];
        }   
    }
    return temp;
}



void main() {
    int amount = GetAmount();
    int array[100];
    GetArray(array, amount);
    int max = maxvalue(array, amount);
    printf("The biggest number which last digit is zero is %i\n ", max);
    system("pause");

}
```

Thank you guys for the answers! That was fast!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You should check if there is a solution, in this example you could check that the value returned by maxValue finishes by 0 (if none of the values finishes by 0 then it would return a[0]):

```
int maxValue(int a[], int n) {
    int temp= a[0]
    for (int i(1); i<n;i++) {
        if (a[i] % 10 == 0 && (temp % 10 != 0 || a[i] > temp )) temp = a[i];
    }
    return temp;
}
```